# using AgGridReact I want to make specific rows selected when grid is binding using ag-grid reactjs

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

```
 <AgGridReact
                // properties
                columnDefs={this.columnDefs}
                rowData={this.state.rowData}
                defaultColDef={this.defaultColDef}
                // events
              //  isRowSelectable={this.isRowSelectable}
                rowSelection={this.rowSelection}
                onSelectionChanged={this.onSelectionChanged.bind(this)}
                frameworkComponents={this.frameworkComponents}
                onGridReady={this.onGridReady}
              ></AgGridReact>
    onGridReady = (params) => {

        this.gridApi = params.api;
        this.gridColumnApi = params.columnApi;
        params.api.sizeColumnsToFit();

      };
```

I know this will work for me **rowNode.setSelected(rowNode.data.id === 58);**
but in which method should I call this.
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, you can set the default selected row once data is set in state

Code snippet :

```
this.setState({ rowData: data },() => {
    this.gridApi.forEachNodeAfterFilter(function(rowNode) {
        rowNode.setSelected(rowNode.data.id === 58);
    });
});
```

**[WORKING DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/hpQ3vpltuKhFvsqN)**

Comment: But I am updating state in componentWillReceiveProps method  `populateBeneficiary = async (clientId) => {
    //if (!beneficiaryTable) {
    //alert(this.props.clientId);
    try {
      //rowData = { id: 1, firstName: "Bilal", lastName: "Khan", address: "PIB" };
      //rowData.push(data);
      const { data: rowData } = await beneService.getBeneficiaries(clientId);
      this.setState({ rowData });
    } catch (error) {
      this.setState({ rowData: [] });
      console.log(error);
    }
  };`

Comment: No issue , you can this.gridApi....  inside callback function of set state as show above.

Comment: Okay sir It is selecting ,but now I am unable to change selection

Comment: @BilalMásInteligente, can you create a demo so I can help you with that, as its working all good in my demo.

Comment: Thank you sir ,problem was that when I click on row, props get updated and make componentWillReceiveProps() to render again ,now i apply condition on it. :)

Comment: @BilalMásInteligente, glad to know, it helped :)

Comment: I want to ask you one more thing, that at first when my component get loaded I fetch data using api and bind it to grid and it makes my specifc rows selected ,but as this is my child component when go foraward and come back it lost selection and when i try to bind grid this time using rowData in state it does not make selection instead force me to fetch data again from api  [check code in script.jsx]https://plnkr.co/edit/NMfvOXwh5VJHyuOF?preview

Comment: same issue it is not selecting row when it falls in If block.

Comment: Dont need your code,create a working demo on codesandbox , it should be running, so I can check the bug.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-tdd-wojkw?file=/component/base.jsx